# bower_concat equivalent for NPM

Tags: angular, npm, gruntjs, bundle, bower

[bower_concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-bower-concat) is great. When you add a bower package using:

```
bower install something --save
```

bower_concat will automatically retrieve the javascript and CSS from that package and concantenate it into a bundle, so you end with a nice vendor.js and vendor.css files that you can then minify and inject in you html.

With the advent of angular2 though, and the Typescript import system, all the packages, including the one used in your app, are going through NPM.

Is there an equivalent of bower_concat for NPM ? It would retrieve you CSS automatically and produce a bundle with it ?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat

Comment: @AngJobs bower_concat is not a simple concat tool. It will extract relevant js and css from package and concatenate them automatically. With grunt-concat I would have to update the grunfile each time I add a dependency.

Comment: I think Webpack can do that, and much more:      https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html   ; the downside, I think, is that Webpack takes some getting-used-to. But you could use a well-tested boilerplate like Angular 2 Webpack starter: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) is definitely the way to go. You have to rework your code a bit, the best being to use ES6 import (use babel to downgrade to ES5 if needed) and webpack will 'just work'(c).

With Webpack you can get rid of `bower`, but also `require` and even `grunt` if your setup is simple enough.

How does it work? It takes a file (the 'main' file) and will then go through the import dependency to pack them into one (or several) files. While it concatenate them you can apply 'loaders'. Loaders are tool which take the file as input and the output will be taken back by Webpack. Loaders can minify, uglify, transpile or apply any arbitrary transformation. THere are many loaders out there.

I am not looking back...

Answer (score 1):

this package is similar your package , see this it will help you
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-minify

Comment: I'm not looking to minify but to just concat. And anyway, if I understand the documentation correctly, you still have to manually specify which modules to minify. bower_concat do that automatically. So you just add a package and it is automatically included in your webapp...